# Can’t get any clue why my cat has a hair loss on chin and arm

Tags: cats, hairloss

my cat first had a bold spot, redness on one of arm. When I touched it, it was bumpy like acne. So I took him a vet and she gave us an antiseptic solution to clean and to prevent any bacterial infection. (Vet said he has no flea)

After a week of antiseptic, all bumps gone and redness gone to baby pink.
It also shows a hair regrowth.

After 12 days of this arm, he has another new one which is a chin.

Has anyone’s cat had this symptom?

My cat has normal activities. He eats, plays well but he has a hair loss and he licks continuously.

PS. I wanna upload a photo but it’s too big…

Comment: For the photo: If you use a phone, do a screenshot of the photo, trim it and upload this. This is usually smaller than the original photo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Just found a bald spot under my cat's chin](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/31634/just-found-a-bald-spot-under-my-cats-chin)